# Find most frequent/common values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to work out the best approach for finding the n most common values in a dataframe. I'm not concerned about row or column they're in, I simply want to find the most common values in the dataframe.

```
Input:
 df = pd.DataFrame({         'A':list('abcdef'),          'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],          'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],          'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],          'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],          'F':list('aaabbb') })
```

```
Desired output:

'a' 4
'4' 4
'1' 3
'b' 2
...
'8' 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
most = df.stack().mode()
```

If need first top value get first value:

```
most = df.stack().mode().iat[0]
```

EDIT For count values use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
count = df.stack().value_counts()
print (count)
5    5
4    5
a    4
b    4
3    3
9    2
7    2
2    2
1    2
f    1
e    1
d    1
c    1
8    1
6    1
0    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets the top value, but I can't get it to work to get the n most common values.

Could I add the value counts for each column?

Comment: @phantom234234 - Unfortunately I have no idea how should looks expected output, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), be free modify `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})` and add expected output DataFrame? Thanks.

Comment: @phantom234234 - Answer is edited, it is what you need?